# How do I use try .. except or if ...else to validate user input?

Tags: python

I want to restrict user input so that a provided `N` obeys `N >0` or `N < 100`.

Should I use `if... else` or `try... except`? Could you provide examples of both approaches?

Comment: I think you probably intended 'and', not 'or' in your condition.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest a combination:)

```
while True:
    value = raw_input('Value between 0 and 100:')
    try:
       value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
       print 'Valid number, please'
       continue
    if 0 <= value <= 100:
       break
    else:
       print 'Valid range, please: 0-100'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: while True:? what does mean? zindel.

Comment: an endless loop actually. This piece of code does not allow program to proceed further until value isn't been input.In general, it is some sort of the `goto` emulation which fits perfectly fine for this sort of tasks imho. Look, there are `break` and `continue` statements inside the cycle - so don't worry - it'll stop at some point ;)

Comment: `while True:` is an idiom for creating an infinite loop (in @zindel's example here, a loop that runs until the user enters a number that's inside the allowed range, so the only way to get past this block of code is to enter a valid integer (or Ctrl+C, I guess...)

Comment: `while True:` loops forever until `break` is encountered or an unhandled exception thrown.  So this code keeps looping until `0 <= value <= 100` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Understand, thanks all of you. :)

Comment: Actually, it's more like emulating `do ... while ...` or `repeat ... until ...` without typing the loop body twice.

Comment: @delnan, right, but `continue` add the real `goto` functionality here

Answer (score 5):

if/else is probably more appropriate here, since any exceptions raised would be ones you threw yourself (and you'd still have to handle them).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be if/else.

But I'd probably do both a validator with if/else and thrown exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
# test value of N
try:
    N = int(N)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('N must be integer')
if N < 0 or N > 100:
    NError = ValueError('N must be between 0 and 100, inclusive.')
    raise NError
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to explain it a little bit, eve if it is right. When there are additional replies, at is your case, show the Pros and Cons of yours.