# Creating a Confirmation function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x

```
def confirm_choice():
    confirm = input("[c]Confirm or [v]Void: ")
    if confirm != 'c' and confirm != 'v':
        print("\n Invalid Option. Please Enter a Valid Option.")
        confirm_choice() 
    print (confirm)
    return confirm
```

When an invalid input has been keyed in for example, the letter 'k' followed by a valid input 'c', the function would print both inputs 'c' and 'k'

Output:

```
c
k
```

How can the above program be altered so that it returns only either 'c' or 'v'and  repeats the function if the input is invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use try .. except or if ...else to validate user input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557937/how-do-i-use-try-except-or-if-else-to-validate-user-input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to return after recursively calling `confirm_choice()` and so it falls out of the if-block and executes

```
print (confirm)
return confirm
```

which will print the first invalid input.

```
def confirm_choice():
    confirm = input("[c]Confirm or [v]Void: ")
    if confirm != 'c' and confirm != 'v':
        print("\n Invalid Option. Please Enter a Valid Option.")
        return confirm_choice() 
    print (confirm)
    return confirm
```

should behave correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Recursion is unnecessary; it's easier to use a `while` loop for this:

```
while True:
    confirm = input('[c]Confirm or [v]Void: ')
    if confirm.strip().lower() in ('c', 'v'):
        return confirm
    print("\n Invalid Option. Please Enter a Valid Option.")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to press `Enter` (i.e., just `c` or `v`)?

Comment: @AstroFloyd See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user) for ways to read single characters.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to the getch package on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/getch/, which basically allows me to replace `input()` with `getch()` or `getche()`.