# Python giving incorrect output when adding 2 values

Tags: python

I am trying to make a calculator program in Python as a bit of a challenge. I am a beginner to python and I am probably making some really obvious mistake. In my calculator I ask the user to define the values and to select the operation they want to use. With the addition operation the calculator gives a strange output. For an example I am telling the calculator to add '7 + 7'. Instead of giving me the correct answer of 14, it gives me 77. Here is my code so far. Hope somebody can help. Cheers

```
#Sets the values for calculator to use
val1 = input ("Enter the first value: ")
val2 = input ("Enter the second value: ")

#Asks what operation to use
print ("1. Add")
print ("2. Subtract")
print ("3. Divide")
print ("4. Multiply")
op = input ("What operation should I use:")

#Addition
if op == '1':
    print(val1, " + ", val2, " = ", (val1 + val2))
```

Comment: typecast to `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user input is of string type. That's why `7` + `7` becomes `77`. You need to convert them to integer using `int()` (or float using `float()`) type to perform arithmetic

```
val1 = int(input ("Enter the first value: "))
val2 = int(input ("Enter the second value: "))
```

As pointed out by @Bailey Parker, in case the user input isn't a number, you can consider using try/except as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557998/4932316)

Comment: This worked, thanks for the help. Will accept answer after the cooldown

Comment: Note that `int` and `float` may raise a `ValueError` if the thing input isn't a number (ex. `int('foo')`). You probably want to do this in a `try`/`except` wrapped in a `while`.

Comment: @BaileyParker: Thanks for the pointer. I added your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

When the + operator's two operands are strings, it will concatenate them together, creating a longer string. You'll need to turn your strings into integers to do math with them.