# How to make inputs other than float and integer to show popups in kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, integer, kivy

I am trying to make a GUI to calculate the amount of paint needed to paint one room in python using kivy.

I want to make the inputs to validate only floats and integers while strings inputs will show popups.

```
def submit(self):
        if self.tinggi.text !="":
            if float(self.tinggi.text) and float(self.lebar.text) and float(self.panjang.text):

                sm.current = "main"

            else:
                invalidForm()

        else:
            invalidForm()
```

I coded it like this but it won't work. It wouldn't continue if I put other than numbers but popups still won't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
try:
   if float(self.tinggi.text) and float(self.lebar.text) and 
    float(self.panjang.text):

           sm.current = "create"

except:
    invalidForm()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. An error said "could not convert string to float:" appeared

Comment: This is the point exactly. You should handle this error with TRY CATCH to show hint for user to only enter the numbers. Something like this: 
    <https://stackoverflow.com/a/5557998/7604642>

Comment: I changed the question a bit. Now, when I enter numbers, it will continue but if I enter other than numbers it won't show popups and the same error message appeared.

Comment: Put it in "Try Except" block. Then raise invalidinput exception for Except part and display a popup inside its code. <https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp> It happens because the IF part gets error. But when you use Try Except, Error handler gives you the opportunity to make the Except code running and then you could raise pop-up and reload the web part. I have updated my code for you. Use that sample.

Comment: Hi  Omid Mosayebiroknkolaie. Can you answer my question on 
"How can I display the input in another screen in kivy?"? I desperately need some help right now.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with KIVY.