# How to update a int value on a .env file using python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have a problem doing this python file . The idea its that this python file could change a int value in a .env file . The problem its that i could change the value of the field in the env , but the value is formated , I insert in the program a number , and in the .env it shows like 'number' , so i want to change it to only the number

```
    import os
import dotenv
import sys
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv




day=input("Insert day: ")

car1=input("Insert car1 : ")

car2=input("Insert car2 : ")

load_dotenv("config.env")
#       print(os.environ["DAY"])  # outputs "valor original"
os.environ["DAY"] = day
#       print(os.environ['DAY'])  # outputs 'valor nuevo'

#       print(os.environ["CAR1"])  # outputs "valor original"
os.environ["CAR1"] = car1
#       print(os.environ['CAR1'])  # outputs 'valor nuevo'

#       print(os.environ["CAR2"])  # outputs "valor original"
os.environ["CAR2"] = car2
#       print(os.environ['CAR2'])  # outputs 'valor nuevo'


dotenv.set_key("config.env", "DAY", os.environ["DAY"])
dotenv.set_key("config.env", "CAR1" , os.environ["CAR1"])
dotenv.set_key("config.env", "CAR2" , os.environ["CAR2"])
```

And in the config.env file it shows like this

```
## Config

SCNAME="EXAMPLE"
DAY='77'

# CAR 1
CAR1='88'


# CAR 2
CAR2='99'
```

When i want that the values i want to change were shown as a int , without ('),like :

```
DAY=77
CAR1=88
CAR2=99
```

Thanks all for attention and helping me guys

Comment: Try using int() before setting variables

Comment: The problem its that if i add a int to make the input in that format , thats who i get when i run the program Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/antonio/Documentos/piton/pruebados.py", line 37, in <module> dotenv.set_key("config.env", "DAY", day) File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 166, in set_key value_out = "'{}'".format(value_to_set.replace("'", "\\'")) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL, DR

```
dotenv.set_key("config.env", "DAY", os.environ["DAY"], quote_mode='never')
```

## Details

When you type, the input is a string.
`day = input(...)` will save a string in `day`.

You should use `int()` to convert it to an integer before saving it in `day`.

```
day = int(input("Insert day: "))
```

However, this can not be secure given that the user can write anything on the keyboard. You can first save the input and check if it is OK. before putting in `day` and writing it in your env file.

```
day_input = input("Insert day: ")

# You can add any other verification to the user input
if not day_input.isdigit():
  # Tell user he made a mistake
else:
  day = int(day_input)
```

You can also use Try-Except to handle these errors:

```
while True:
    value = input('write an integer between 1 and 31')
    try:
       value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
       print('Valid integer, please')
       continue
    if value > 0 and value <= 31 : # Ok
       break
    else:
       print('Valid range, please: 1-31')
```

see [How do I use try .. except or if ...else to validate user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557937/how-do-i-use-try-except-or-if-else-to-validate-user-input)

Moreover, you cannot put integer values in `.env` files. These accept only strings as values.

```
def set_key(
    dotenv_path: Union[str, _PathLike],
    key_to_set: str,
    value_to_set: str,
    quote_mode: str = "always",
    export: bool = False,
    encoding: Optional[str] = "utf-8",
) -> Tuple[Optional[bool], str, str]:
```

This is extracted from the  `set_key()` method from `dotenv` and you can see that it accepts only str type for value argument. `os.environ` checks that also. So you cannot put directly integers there.

However, in `dotenv.set_key()`, you can see that there is a `quote_mode`. You can write :

```
dotenv.set_key("config.env", "DAY", os.environ["DAY"], quote_mode='never')
```

You can either use another format instead of .env or you can make sure to convert values before and after writing/reading the env file.

Comment: The problem its that if i add a int to make the input in that format , thats who i get when i run the program Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antonio/Documentos/piton/pruebados.py", line 37, in <module>
    dotenv.set_key("config.env", "DAY", day)
  File "/home/antonio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 166, in set_key
    value_out = "'{}'".format(value_to_set.replace("'", "\\'"))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Actually, you cannot put integer values in .env files. It accepts only strings as values. You can either use another format instead of .env or  you can make sure to convert values before and after writing/reading the env file.

Comment: I cant put integer values in env files in any other language ? or only happens with python?

Comment: .env files are normally used to specify values of environment variables and these must be strings. So It will be the same in every language. You can write also some code to write anything in the .env (in the end it is just a text file). But it would be better to use a JSON file to write these key-value pairs and there are good libraries in all languages to deal with JSONs.

Comment: So any languages can insert integers on it?

Comment: i mean if in any language it can be done on a .env file

Comment: I am sorry, I checked and I just found out. I discovered that there is a `quote_mode` in `set_key()`. You can set it to never.